# how to set texts in text-area at different font and size?

Tags: java, editor, textarea

Im in designing a Simple text editor in which I have to change text colors 
of difnt wolrds like 'for','while','if','else' etc. I also want to change  size of 
text . How it is possible . thans in  advance.(Please send proper/possoble reasons for failure of such a things in JAVA)

Comment: Are you using a `JTextArea` or a `JTextPane`?

Comment: I have not ever used JTextPane. I thing i have to try some blogs. there nothing in about JtextPane **Java Black book**.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start with [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

If you've no idea where to start, then the best thing to do would be to read the [Swing text component tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Comment: +1 e.g. [`HTMLDocumentEditor`](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276).

Comment: thanks but wanted to know all hierarchy of that container->panel->pane  something like that